# opencv error : bad argument (bad image header) in cvCloneImage file build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxarray.cpp, line 3122

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

sorry for my english..

i'm new to opencv, and i want to try samples square.cpp,i used codeblocks on ubuntu.

but i got error when i compiled and run it, it said that (on Xterm):

**opencv error : bad argument (bad image header) in cvCloneImage file build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxarray.cpp, line 3122**

so, my question is, how to fix it?

thanks.

Comment: Does it happen with newer versions too? 2.1.0 is a little old. 2.4.1 is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

It may contain some code which is using some input images. The important thing is that those input images might not be null.

This error comes in `cxarray.cpp` where we have the code like `if (!CV_IS_IMAGE_HDR(src))`. Now if you check for the definition of this

```
#define CV_IS_IMAGE_HDR
```

You will get it as:

```
((img) != NULL && ((const IplImage*)(img))->nSize == sizeof(IplImage))
```

The first thing it checks is for null image. So in your case you might not have the input image with you.
Select a input image you have and then try again. It will work, as it have worked for me.

Comment: i already copied 6 image named "pic1.png", "pic2.png"......, "pic6.png", on the same folder with my codeblocks project. 
but still have that error.

Comment: still didn't get it, so, how do i select a input image? what syntax i should use?